# Entity Framework 5 - Calling a stored procedure with parameters. Parameter not recognized

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF 5 app and I'm trying to call a stored procedure which takes a single parameter, as follows:

[image]

As you can see, I am supplying a parameter, and it's the correct name. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?
The image may be a bit hard to see. The error says:

"Procedure or function 'AddRowToPanelCdClAllData' expects parameter '@SubId' which was not supplied."

The line of code generating the error is as follows:

```
  internal void AddRowToPanelCdClAllData(string subId) 
    {
        this.Database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("AddRowToPanelCdClAllData", new SqlParameter("@SubId", subId));
    }
```

The value of 'subId' contains a value and is not null.

Comment: can you post the code line and the error as text instead of an image? it's impossible to read what that image says

Comment: This often occurs when the parameter you specify has a `NULL` value but the stored procedure parameter does not accept `NULLs`.  Can you double check that `subId` does have a value?

Comment: @AndrewCounts http://i.stack.imgur.com/DzHyf.png

Comment: Have you checked if subId is null or not?

Comment: @AndrewCounts - Thank you. I modified my post.

Comment: @MartinParkin - The value of 'subId' is not null.

Comment: What type of value is the stored procedure accepting? Based upon name I would assume int/long, and I believe it will not convert this for you. So you may need to parse the parameter subId into an appropriate variable or explicitly set the type property on the SqlParameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
this.Database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("AddRowToPanelCdClAllData @SubId",
                                          new SqlParameter("SubId", subId));
```

Comment: I can't believe it, but that works. I never would have thought to try that.

Comment: What about multiple parameters?